# Java : Array se lee o se escribe mal de un archivo

Tags: java, array, algoritmos, ordenamiento, serialización

Querría resolver un problema de conseguir todas las combinaciones posibles para que varias personas recorran un camino, de modo que dos nodos no pueden ser visitados por varias personas.

El caso ideal sería almacenar los elementos en una lista pero al utilizar recursividad los elementos de la lista al final serían null.

El caso es que he realizado un algoritmo que me imprime todas las soluciones y las imprime bien el caso es que quiero guardarlas en un archivo, entonces en vez de imprimirlas las escribo en un archivo.

El caso es que cuando las leo los elementos que yo había introducido como [1,2,3], [2,1,3], [1,3,2], [2,3,1], [3,1,2] y [3,2,1] son leídas todas como [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3] ,[1,2,3], [1,2,3] y [1,2,3].

¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto ?

Código:

```
 package elements;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Combine{

    public static final int nNodes = 3;
    public static final int nVehicles = 3;

    private  ObjectOutputStream output= new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("Solutions.bin"));
    // nodes
    private Node[] nodes;
    private int nUnvisitedNodes = nNodes;
    private List<Node[][]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // solution
    private Node[][] sol = new Node[nVehicles][];

    // no of solutions already found and printed
    int nSolutions = 0;

    public Combine() throws IOException {
        // init nodes
        nodes = new Node[nNodes];
        for (int nix = 0; nix < nodes.length; nix++) {
            nodes[nix] = new Node(nix + 1); // node names are 1-based
        }

        // search for solutions -- person 0 first
        tryVehicle0();
        try {

            ObjectOutputStream output= new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("numberSols.txt"));
            output.writeInt(nSolutions);
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output.close();
        readSolution();

        this.print();



    }

    private void tryVehicle0() {
        if (nUnvisitedNodes == 0) { // done
            storeSolution();
        } else {
            // assuming this is not the last person, this person may visit 1 through nUnvisitedNodes nodes
            // (in a canonical solution person 0 cannot visit 0 nodes)
            int maxVisits = nUnvisitedNodes;
            for (int nNodesToVisit = 1; nNodesToVisit <= maxVisits; nNodesToVisit++) {
                sol[0] = new Node[nNodesToVisit];
                tryNode(0, sol[0], 0);
                sol[0] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryVehicle(int person) {
        assert person > 0;
        if (nUnvisitedNodes == 0) { // solution complete
            storeSolution();
        } else {
            if (person < nVehicles) { // still persons to try
                if (person == nVehicles - 1) { // this is the last person
                    // person must visit all remaining nodes
                    // in a canonical solution, first node must be greater than first node visited by previous person
                    int nNodesToVisit = nUnvisitedNodes;
                    sol[person] = new Node[nNodesToVisit];
                    tryNodeWithMininum(person, sol[person], 0, sol[person - 1][0].name + 1);
                    sol[person] = null;
                } else {
                    // since this is not the last person, this person may visit 1 through nUnvisitedNodes nodes
                    // in a canonical solution, first node must be greater than first node visited by previous person
                    int maxVisits = nUnvisitedNodes;
                    for (int nNodesToVisit = 1; nNodesToVisit <= maxVisits; nNodesToVisit++) {
                        sol[person] = new Node[nNodesToVisit];
                        tryNodeWithMininum(person, sol[person], 0, sol[person - 1][0].name + 1);
                        sol[person] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryNode(int person, Node[] personSol, int nix) {
        if (nix == personSol.length) { // this person's solution complete
            tryVehicle(person + 1);
        } else {
            for (Node candidateNode : nodes) {
                if (this.visit(candidateNode)) {
                    personSol[nix] = candidateNode;
                    tryNode(person, personSol, nix + 1);
                    personSol[nix] = null;
                    this.unvisit(candidateNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryNodeWithMininum(int person, Node[] personSol, int nix, int minNodeName) {
        for (Node candidateNode : nodes) {
            if (candidateNode.getName() >= minNodeName) {
                if ( this.visit(candidateNode)) {
                    personSol[nix] = candidateNode;
                    tryNode(person, personSol, nix + 1);
                    personSol[nix] = null;
                    this.unvisit(candidateNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void storeSolution() {
        nSolutions++;
        Node[][] sol2 = Arrays.copyOf(sol, sol.length);
        try {
            output.writeObject(sol);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void readSolution(){
        try {
            ObjectInputStream input=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("numberSols.txt"));
            int numberSol = input.readInt();
            input.close();
            ObjectInputStream input2=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Solutions.bin"));


            for(int i=0; i < numberSol; i++){
                Node[][] node = (Node[][]) input2.readObject();
                this.list.add(node);

            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void print(){
        int i=1;
        for(Node[][] node: this.list){
            System.out.println("Sol "+i);
            for (int pix = 0; pix < nVehicles; pix++) {
                System.out.println(" Vehicle " + pix + " = " + Arrays.toString(node[pix]));
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Combine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** visits node if not already visited */
    public boolean visit(Node node) {
        if (node.visited) {
            return false;
        } else {
            node.visited = true;
            nUnvisitedNodes--;
            return true;
        }
    }

    /** undoes visit (that is, backtracks) */
    public void unvisit(Node node) {
        assert node.visited : node.getName();
        nUnvisitedNodes++;
        node.visited = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien por qué solo escribes un entero en el archivo. Lo que deberías hacer es utilizar la misma lógica de impresión de pantalla pero en lugar de usar el stream de consola usar el stresm del archivo.

Comment: Y así lo hago. El entero se escribe en otro archivo, simplemente aunque no es necesario, para tener el numero de soluciones.

Comment: Si tu problema es con la serializacion, entonces trata de reducir tu codigo al problema concreto que tienes, es penoso tener que entender todo tu código, sobre todo porque no está bien explicado. De paso, es confuso usar la extension ".txt" para un archivo que -al parecer- no es de texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El caso es que **he realizado un algoritmo que me imprime todas las soluciones y las imprime bien** el caso es que quiero guardarlas en un archivo, entonces en vez de imprimirlas las escribo en un archivo.

Tu codigo es bastante caos, pero la respuesta mas obvia a tu problema es que siempre **escribes** el mismo dato en el archivo, ya que tu algoritmo de impresion parece funcionar correctamente.

---

Ahora voy a apostar y dire que esto lo causa el que no uses la variable `sol2` que creas en el metodo `storeSolution`:

```
private void storeSolution() {
    nSolutions++;
    Node[][] sol2 = Arrays.copyOf(sol, sol.length);
    try {
        // output.writeObject(sol);
        output.writeObject(sol2);
        //                    ↑ usa sol2!!!!!
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```